# What to do with pots with no holes in?

Tags: containers

As far as I'm aware, the majority of plants require good drainage and don't like sitting in water. So what is the purpose of and what do I do with a pot that has no drainage holes in the bottom?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments already, this is an outer pot where the inner pot goes in. So the inner pot is usually a plastic container with holes. When watering your plants, water drains through the holes and such an outer pot captures this water (just like a saucer would do as well). These outer pots are usually used indoor, so you can keep your windowsill clean. You ask (in comments), what to do with the surplus water after watering. Very simple, just wait like 20 minutes or so and remove the surplus water. Or try to dose the water so that there will not be any surplus water.

I use this system of inner and outer pots for almost all my indoor plants (see for example on my profile pic.). I think it looks nicer than containers put on saucers (but that's a matter of personal preference).

Answer (score 1):

Drill holes into the bottom with a masonry bit.

Comment: Is there a risk of cracking the pot when doing this? One big hole or lots of little holes?

Comment: With a nice sharp masonry bit I have never had an issue; with water as a lubricant or not.  Just can't use much force and make sure you back it up with a piece of wood to alleviate any pressure.  The bigger the hole, the more you risk I would think.  I just use a 1/4" bit and make three or four holes.

Answer (score 1):

Drill hole(s) in it. Masonry bits ( carbide tip) , do not turn fast and use water. I get neater holes using a smaller bit like 1/4 " to make the initial hole then use 1/2" bit to make a larger hole. A regular electric drill does best- you do not want impact.

Answer (score 0):

If this is plastic, try poking some holes in the bottom with a hot screwdriver.

Comment: It's ceramic so I'm afraid it would crack if I tried to drill it

Comment: I've drilled ceramic pots many times. You turn them upside down, and drill from the outside in. Always use water around t6he drill bit. 
It keeps the ceramic from getting over-hot.